# .NET PrintDocument.Print() data format

Tags: c#, .net, windows, printing

My program ( written on .NET c sharp) uses  method PrintDocument.Print() for print.
My company wants to speed up print process. It can be done with  print controller(hardware device).
 So I need  to know which  data format  .NET PrintDocument.Print()  uses. And then order  corresponding controller.
**Question is -which  data format  .NET PrintDocument.Print()  uses for print?**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print(v=vs.110).aspx.
I think this would be helping you to find an answer.

Comment: i see this link, alas, but the link above is no information about the format data of the print and about how learn it

Comment: No, it can not be done with PrintController.  There is no standard data format, it is entirely up to the manufacturer's printer driver.  Which emulates a graphics device, not unlike your monitor.  The only way to make it faster is to print less.  Avoid bitmaps.

Comment: Hans Passant , sorry for my english, but i meant print controller as hardware device, not library class. So I need to know correct data format to choose hardware print controller